# Wordpress ACF Plugin with Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, advanced-custom-fields

Using the ACF Plugin I created a field called 'slideshow_images' and within the repeater, I had a field named 'image'.

My original bootstrap HTML code is as follows:

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
    </a>
</header>
```

I included the PHP into the code above as follows:

```
<?php if(get_field('slideshow_images')): ?>
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      <?php $z = 0; while(the_repeater_field('slideshow_images')): ?>
      <?php $z = $z + 1; $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'full'); ?>
          <div class="<?php echo ($z==1) ? 'active ' : ''; ?>item">
              <div class="fill" style="background-image: url(<?php the_sub_field('image');?>);"></div>
          </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      </div>
      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
      </a>
  </header>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, when I add my images and preview the site. Nothing shows up. There are no errors at all. When I view source, everything seems to be just fine but all I get is a Blank carousel(you can still see the indicators). What seems to be the issue?